# How to create an histogram with inner divisions in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a column of grades on a Google Sheets document and I want to generate something like that:

[image]

I only managed to create a simple histogram with custom bucket size, but I want it to be more informative and show the distribution of the grades in each bucket. Is that possible? If so, how?

I also tried the *Stacked* chart type, but haven't succeed in doing what I'm looking for.

Comment: The "histogram with inner divisions" looks like a stacked bar chart. Have you tried to create one?

Comment: I actually did, but it didn't looked like I expected, maybe I missed some configurations of it?

Comment: I walked through everything in the `customize` tab, but no luck. Maybe I need to arrange my data in a different way?

Comment: Downvoter - explain?

Comment: This explanation may help - https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-stacked-bar-chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of grades in the form of raw data, to use a stacked bar chart to make an histogram first you should create a table of [frequency distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_distribution). Since you want to show "inner divisions" you should include a column for each "division".

The shape of the table of frequency distribution with inner divisions should look like the following

```
        +0   +1   +2    +3    +4
50-54
55-59
...
```

If you don't wan't to do this by yourself then you could look if there is a Google Sheets add-on for statistics similar to [Statistics](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/statistics/efmdpnlalflhfpggddihbefikjllkifc?hl=en) (AFAIK it hasn't an histogram with "inner divisions")

Related Google Sheets Functions

- [FREQUENCY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094286?hl=en)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Related Q&A

- [Create chart with total for each score](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/56777/88163)